# Eclipse IDE Redo and Inspect key command Conflicts

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide

This is really irritating me , Am using Eclipse IDE(JUNO) In Apple MacBook Pro Mountain Lion for my project development, 
whenever i press `Cmd + Shift + z` instead of redo action , i am getting an popup in bottom right corner like below,

[image]

i even tried to change the key comands in `Eclipse => Preferences => General => Keys` , but nothing is working, always getting this popup.

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've been suffering with this issue too and just found the solution:

With Eclipse **not** running, edit **org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi** and search for **'COMMAND+SHIFT+Z'**.  You'll find two **`<bindings>`** instances -  one pertains to **Redo** and one to **Inspect**.  You'll need to do a search on the **command="xxxx"** attribute to do a lookup to see which one belongs to the **`<commands>`** with **elementId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.redo"** and which one belongs to the one with **elementId="org.eclipse.php.debug.ui.commands.Inspect"**.

Once you've determined which *`<bindings>`* is for *Inspect*, **change** its **keySequence** to something other than 'COMMAND+SHIFT+Z' to remove the conflict.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with shortcuts. Have you restarted Eclipse after updating the key bindings be to non-conflicting? That was needed for me, but after that, it was consistently working.

Comment: actually, its not an conflict, Inspect key binding is `Shift + Cmd + I` and Redo binding is `Shift + Cmd + Z` , both have different commands, but dont know , why its showing same key code for both on this popup

Comment: And restarting after changing the key commands doesn't help in my case!

Comment: Ok, that is interesting - the pop-up menu should only show if there are key conflicts. My only other idea is that somehow a bad binding is written to the new Eclipse xmi workbench; you could try to delete the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder from your workspace directory. Warning, this will lose your UI configuration, e.g. open views, editors and perspectives, but might solve the issue. Of course this only helps if you are using a 4.x version of the Eclipse platform.

Comment: nope! even that dint slove the issue, i have tried it in JUNO, KELPER , nothing worked, still getting the same popup